# Using CFolderPickerDialog for the purpose of 'Save As' (MFC)

Tags: mfc, cfiledialog

I would like to use a `CFolderPickerDialog` instance for the purpose of 'Save As'.

In other words, the user will input the name of a (new) folder, which I can then create.

With the `CFileDialog` base class, this can be done during construction via the first input argument:

```
BOOL bOpenFileDialog // TRUE for FileOpen, FALSE for FileSaveAs
```

How can I go about achieving the same functionality for a `CFolderPickerDialog` instance?

Comment: It looks like only the open dialog supports the folder picker mode. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn457282(v=vs.85).aspx): _`FOS_PICKFOLDERS` Present an Open dialog that offers a choice of folders rather than files._ - As workaround you may use the regular file save dialog and only use the folder portion of the selected file path.

Comment: @zett42: Yes, that's exactly what I had in mind after reading the answer posted below. More accurately, just create a folder with the name selected by the user (regardless of whether or not it has an extension). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it just came to my mind that you can in fact use the full "file" path as the folder path to create. Another suggestion - call `dialog.GetIFileSaveDialog()->SetFileNameLabel(L"&Folder:");` to rename the label of the edit control appropriately. Maybe you even find a way to hide the file extension combo box (`CFileDialog::HideControl()` maybe).

Answer (score 2):

You can not achieve this with [CFolderPickerDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795962.aspx) as per my understanding. 
Le me explain you this. Base class of [CFolderPickerDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795962.aspx) is [CFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk77e5e7.aspx) and `bOpenFileDialog` the flag which will allow you to launch file dialog as open or save.

Since, [CFolderPickerDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795962.aspx) is child class hence microsoft has to provide call to parent ([CFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk77e5e7.aspx)) in constructor. If you open `dlgfile.cpp` from `..\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\` then you will get source code of [CFolderPickerDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795962.aspx) class.

Now coming to point, if you observe the constructor of [CFolderPickerDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795962.aspx) then you get exact reason why its not possible.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Folder Picker common dialog helper

CFolderPickerDialog::CFolderPickerDialog(LPCTSTR lpszFolder, DWORD dwFlags, CWnd* pParentWnd, DWORD dwSize, BOOL fNonFileSystemFolders) :
    CFileDialog(TRUE, NULL, lpszFolder, dwFlags, NULL, pParentWnd, dwSize, TRUE)
{
    m_bPickFoldersMode = TRUE;
    m_bPickNonFileSysFoldersMode = fNonFileSystemFolders;
}
```

First flag is always true that indicate unfortunately,  [CFolderPickerDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795962.aspx) will open in File Open mode only.

Comment: This is not a matter of the parameters supported by the MFC wrapper class `CFolderPickerDialog`. The underlying common item dialog simply does not support the combination of save dialog and folder picker mode. In fact, I even tried to derive my own folder picker dialog from `CFileDialog` that would set the first `CFileDialog` parameter to `FALSE` but this makes the internal call to `IFileDialog::SetOptions()` fail with `E_INVALIDARG`.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that I will just use a `CFileDialog` instance configured in 'Save As' mode, and create a folder with the name selected by the user (regardless of whether or not it has an extension).

Comment: @zett42 Thank you for information. I learn this newly. however, I just want to make point that,CFolderPickerDialog will not support save open flag. :)